Statistical significance of multiple models over multiple datasets
I have a table of mean performances of 6 models over 10 datasets. While I've seen tables like these in research papers, they always display significant results in bold. What I'm not sure of is how these tests are conducted? The results are better significantly in comparison to what exactly? I do conduct Friedman test with Nemenyi correction and also Wilcoxon for pairwise comparisons, but when it comes to this type of tables below, I'm not sure how to proceed!


"What I'm not sure of is how these tests are conducted? The results are better significantly in comparison to what exactly? " These are good questions, and as a reviewer I'd ask the people who do this to explain what exactly they are doing. This should not be guesswork for strangers on the internet.

One would need more precise references to be able to guess what the sort of significance test is. There are many options here. The current answer, comparing likelihoods, is completely different from what I thought which is comparing the outputs of two models on different datasets as input to a test, for example a paired samples t-test.

Also, significant results in bold, that is not very common for multiple pairwise comparisons. In such a case, when 'significance' can have multiple interpretations because of multiple pairs, one often uses letters to denote the groups among which no significant differences occur.

When computing $p$ values for model comparison, this usually assumes the model is fit on the same data, which probably doesn't apply in your case given you have many datasets. However, I do talk a bit about how this is done on models which do share the same fitted datasets.
I can't know how the models were compared in the cases you mentioned elsewhere, where the details will matter. The primary ways I typically see for $p$-value based tests of model comparisons are those which use either $F$ tests or $\chi^2$ versions like the likelihood ratio tests (LRTs), which use the log likelihood of different models. The $p$ value is obtained from either a comparison of the fitted model and a naive model (such as intercept-only regression) or multiple fitted models. An example below is shown in R:
#### Load Library ####
library(lmtest)

#### Fit Two Models ####
fit1 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, iris)
fit2 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width, iris)

#### Compare ####
anova(fit1,fit2) # uses F test
lrtest(fit1,fit2) # uses LRT test

Where you can see the results below show the $F$ test and LRT test:
> anova(fit1,fit2) # uses F test
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width
Model 2: Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1    148 33.845                                  
2    147 30.755  1    3.0898 14.768 0.0001804 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> lrtest(fit1,fit2) # uses LRT test
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width
Model 2: Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width
  #Df   LogLik Df Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
1   3 -101.177                        
2   4  -93.997  1 14.36   0.000151 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Note that for a set of OLS regressions like these, the difference in which testing is used probably isn't that consequential. There are also non-$p$-value methods like AIC/BIC which are quite common.
